# datamash: dealing with empty values in column

Tags: bash, statistics

I'm using `datamash` to evaluate columns of price data. In looking through the `man` page, I don't see any clear path for dealing with the following.

```
The Viridian convict / by York, Sam,    YORK    B       F       15.00   15.00
Show me a mountain / by Young, Kerry,   YOUNG   B       F       27.00   27.00
Eve / by Young, William P.      YOUNG   B       F       27.00   27.00
The gates of Evangeline / by Young, Hester.     YOUNG   B       F       26.00   26.00
Meddling and murder / by Yu, Ovidia,    YU      B       F       
Vision of the future / by Zahn, Timothy.        ZAHN    B       F       8.00    8.00
Star wars. by Zahn, Timothy,    ZAHN    B       F       
Wicked bite / by Zanetti, Rebecca,      ZANETTI B       F       15.00   15.00
```

Note the missing values in 2 columns. I have not found a way to get `datamash` to deal with missing values without preprocessing using other tools.

Ex.

```
awk -F'\t' '$6 != "" {print $6}' print.csv | datamash mean 1 sstdev 1 median 1
```

The `--narm` option seemed promising but didn't help at all. I get the following:

> datamash: invalid numeric value in line 1 field 6: ''

I can continue to use pipes if that's what it takes but I'm new to this tool and suspect there is an easier way.

Comment: I don't see an option in datamash supporting this. There is the `--no-strict --filler <val>` pair, this works for the `transpose` operation. Doesn't seem to work other operations. Doing transpose twice will fill it in. Not sure I'd call it a solution, but for small files it works. e.g. `cat file.csv | datamash transpose --no-strict --filler 0.0 | datamash transpose | datamash mean 6`

Comment: @JonDeg Thanks! That might work but it is the same complexity level as what I'm doing now and no more clear.